# Exim does not verify users

Tags: dovecot, exim

After adding the configuration bit:

```
deny
        message = invalid recipient
        domains = +local_domains
        !verify = recipient/callout=no_cache
```

from: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LMTP/Exim running update-exim4.conf and service exim4 restart

the server is still accepting emails to recipients that do not exist in dovecot.

I'm using LMTP to deliver the emails to dovecot on the same machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's look like a XY problem ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284253 ) Can you explain desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do as described bellow:

```
domainlist local_domains = my.domain.com
hostlist   relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1 : 192.168.0.0/16 : 10.0.0.0/8
domainlist relay_to_domains = my.relay1.domain.com : my.relay2.domain.com
...
begin acl
...
acl_check_rcpt:
...
# Allow authenticated users
  accept  authenticated = *

# Deny if sender isn't exist
  accept  hosts = +relay_from_hosts : \
                       ${if exists{/etc/exim/host_whitelist} \
                       {/etc/exim/host_whitelist}{} }
          endpass
          message       = sender mailbox not found
          verify = sender

# Check if recipient exists in local and relay domains
  accept  domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
          endpass
          message = recipient mailbox not found
          verify  = recipient

# Deny all others (this is the last checking rule)
  deny    message       = relay not permitted

acl_check_predata:
...
```

I'm not using recipients checking in transports and routers sections. And it works perfectly.

Comment: So would this work with LMTP. I'm not infront of a terminal right now. :/

Comment: No, my example is for SMTP. Before all SMTP server  checks recipients then SMTP server gives message body and routing it to dovecot. Lmtp isn't used on 25 smtp port, it's used only for delivery message (routing) when message is accepted by SMTP server.

Comment: This part:
```# Deny if sender isn't exist
  accept  hosts = +relay_from_hosts : \
                       ${if exists{/etc/exim/host_whitelist} \
                       {/etc/exim/host_whitelist}{} }
          endpass
          message       = sender mailbox not found
          verify = sender```

only allows users from your own domain, right?

Comment: No. It allow for ralay_from_hosts without checking mail senders. Read about `endpass` in exim documentation.